# Default destructor in Dart?

Tags: dart, destructor

In C++ if I define a class that has some members then the class destructor (ie `dispose` method) will destruct every member in reverse order by default, unless I explicitly write something else. For example, if I define:

```cpp
class Foo, Bar, Baz;
class MyClass {
  MyClass(Foo _foo, Bar _bar, Baz _baz) : foo(_foo), bar(_bar), baz(_baz);
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
  Baz baz;
}
```

Then the destructor for this class will be equivalent to:

```cpp
MyClass::~MyClass() {
  delete baz;  // calls Baz::~Baz, the destructor of Baz
  delete bar;
  delete foo;
  // ...destruct superclasses (not applicable here)
}
```

This is usually what the destructor should look like so it saves a lot of time and avoids memory leaks when you add a member but forget to update the destructor.

In Dart, on this page: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input I see there's an overriden `dispose` method which looks like the analog of a C++ destructor. This override simply destructs all members and then the superclass.

My question is: does Dart have a facility for implicit destructors like C++ does, or is this `dispose` boilerplate always necessary when you have class members? If it is required, is it only needed for complex types or are string members etc. automatically disposed?

Comment: Dart does not have destructors.  Objects are automatically garbage collected when no longer referenced, but there is no automatic way to be notified exactly when that occurs.  For non-memory resources that need to be released, you need to rely on manual management with explicit functions (a common convention is with a `dispose` method).

Comment: @jamesdlin ahhh I see, thanks!